# A list where each attribute is a string of words, and splitting each attribute into a new list where the new attributes are every word

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner python programmer and new to this forum website. I've searched around and haven't been able to find what I've been looking for, so I came here.

I have a function that calculates the percent error between two values given from user input, writes that value to a file in the string: 'Trial x % error = y', where x is the trial number and y equals the float value of the percent error. Every time this function is run, it adds a new line to the file and writes, 'Trial (x + 1) % error = y', this way it is easy to track your trials. The function then turns each line in the file into an attribute of a list, and prints to the console the last item in that list.

To fix this, I decided a way to do this was to: split each attribute in the list (which is a string of words) where a space is, and save each word in a line to its own list. This way I could index the second attribute in the new list and save it to the value x, add 1 to it, and that would be the new value of x.

```
def percentError():
    x = 1
    #defining formula
    error = str(100 * (measured - accepted) / (accepted))
    #opening % Error.txt
    errorTxt =  open('% Error.txt', 'a')
    #writing in file
    errorTxt.write('Trial ' + str(x) + ' % error = ' + error + '%')
    #new line
    errorTxt.write('\n')
    #close file
    errorTxt.close()
    #open file again
    errorTxt = open('% Error.txt', 'r')
    #read from and print what is read
    trial = []
    trialNum = []
    for line in errorTxt:
      trial.append(line.strip())
    print(trial[-1])
    for attribute in trial[-1]:
       z = trial.split(' ')
       trialNum.append(z)
    x = trialNum[1]
    #file close
    errorTxt.close()
```

There's code above the comment (#defining formula) that has user inputs for the variables of measured and accepted, I left it out for readability.

This gives me the error - AttributeError: 'list' has no attribute 'split'

Anyone know how to fix my problem? The goal is to have x only increase by 1 from the highest trial number in the file.

Comment: You can't split a list of strings, you can however split a string. Maybe `z = attribute.split(' ')` instead of `z = trial.split(' ')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple tokenizer with the `re` module. Maybe like this:

```
import re
def simple_tokenize(text):
    return re.sub(r"\W", " ", text).split()
```

Then you can turn your list of text strings into a list of list of words like:

```
data_in = [
    "To be, or not to be, that is the question:",
    "Whether ’tis nobler in the mind to suffer",
    "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,",
    "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,",
    "And by opposing end them?"
]

data_out = [simple_tokenize(line) for line in data_in]

print(data_out)
```

Giving you:

```
[
    ['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question'],
    ['Whether', 'tis', 'nobler', 'in', 'the', 'mind', 'to', 'suffer'],
    ['The', 'slings', 'and', 'arrows', 'of', 'outrageous', 'fortune'],
    ['Or', 'to', 'take', 'arms', 'against', 'a', 'sea', 'of', 'troubles'],
    ['And', 'by', 'opposing', 'end', 'them']
]
```

Looking at your specific code and your description of what you want to do in the end, I think there is a lot of it you can remove and a bunch of the work/splitting/parsing you are doing is redundant.

If you want to:

- Calculate the percent error between two values given from user input.
- writes that value to a file in the string: 'Trial x % error = y'
- the function to determine trial based on prior data

You might try:

```
def percentError(measured, accepted):
    error = 100 * (measured - accepted) / (accepted)

    with open('percent_error.txt', 'a+') as error_file:
        error_file.seek(0)

        try:
            last_line = error_file.readlines()[-1]
            last_trial_number = int(last_line.split()[1])
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            last_trial_number = 0

        last_line = f"Trial {last_trial_number  +1} % error = {error}%"
        error_file.write(f"{last_line}\n")

    print(last_line)

percentError(10,8)
percentError(10,9)
percentError(10,7)

user_measured = int(input("enter measured: ")) ## note this is brittle and will error if the user enters bad data
user_accepted = int(input("enter accepted: ")) ## note this is brittle and will error if the user enters bad data
percentError(user_measured, user_accepted)
```

Should show you:

```
Trial 1 % error = 25.0%
Trial 2 % error = 11.11111111111111%
Trial 3 % error = 42.857142857142854%
```

and a 4th trial based on your user input.

then it will generate a file "percent_error.txt" with the same results

Comment: Sounds great! Yeah as a beginner I am not used to incorporating parameters and arguments into my functions, as I mostly code in a linear way, instead of thinking of more efficient and other ways to do things. 
So if we wanted to use user input, would we subsitute the arguments in the percentError() call with float(input('measured  = ')) ?

Comment: Technically one could do: `percentError(int(input("enter measured: ")), int(input("enter accepted: ")))` but I would prompt for those values individually into proper variables prior to calling `percentError()`. I'll update the code to prompt for a 4th call with user input now.

Comment: Shweet, this is definitely more concise. Don't worry about the brittle inputs, I used try: and except: in a loop to re-prompt the user if they enter strings

The only problem now is still my original problem. After running my program, if I go in and delete the last line in the file, x is now set to 1 again. I wanted to add this feature if someone enters the wrong numbers and wants to delete that trial without messing up the trial numbers.

Thanks for everything so far and sorry if I'm bothering you

Comment: You should be able to delete any or all of the lines in the file and even the complete file itself and things should pick up where they were left off. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not happening. If I run my program, enter two trials, delete the last one, it writes 'Trial 1 % error = y' instead of the last one + 1

Comment: <edit> found the issue, I was leaving an extra line of blank space in, so it was reading that as the last line in the file, returning the trial num as 0, so the next iteration was 1 </edit>